# Typescript Error "Object is of type 'unknown'."

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Yesterday, whilst working on the codebase, we had no issues whatsoever.

This morning, on the other hand, we have walked into every error being treated as `Unknown` vs the previous `any` type.

How can I revert this change. I can only find a pile of terribly confusing github convos which allude to the change, but none which actually specify in which version this breaking change was added.

TIA.

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem further, maybe with a code example? What is broken now and which error message to you get at the moment, did you update dependencies?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> none which actually specify in which version this breaking change was added

This is a new feature of TypeScript 4.4. Catch parameters now default to `unknown`. This makes the error handling safer. As you have found `"useUnknownInCatchVariables": false` is one workaround.

However I recommend not setting this option to allow safety for future code, and instead adding explicit `any` if that makes sense or adding custom type guards to take benefit from the safety in existing code.

## More

- TypeScript official blog post : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/
- I also did a video on the subject : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyBvFey7pVc

Answer (score 4):

After a ton of googling, I found this in a playground comment...

`"useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,` in your compiler options will fix it.